# What does 'docker inspect -f .' do?

Tags: docker, inspect

I tried the following:

```
$ docker inspect -f . ubuntu:latest
.
$ docker inspect -f . hello-world
.
```

I read that inspect returns basic information about container or image. But when I execute above command with a dot, it returns me a dot. What does it mean?

Comment: what is the dot supposed to do? why are you including it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing this was supposed to be:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{ . }}' ubuntu:latest
```

which would produce the object formatted output, e.g.:

```
{sha256:2fa927b5cdd31cdec0027ff4f45ef4343795c7a2d19a9af4f32425132a222330 [ubuntu:latest] []   2016-05-27T14:15:02.359284074Z b8bd6a8e8874a87f626871ce370f4775bdf598865637082da2949ee0f4786432 0xc4201f8280 1.9.1  0xc4201f8500 amd64 linux  121989688 121989688 {aufs map[]} {layers [sha256:9436069b92a3ec23351313d6decc5fba2ce1cd52aac77dd8da3b03b3dfcb5382 sha256:19429b698a2283bfaece7f590e438662e2078351a9ad077c6d1f7fb12f8cd08d sha256:82b57dbc5385a2a0edd94dfc86f9e4d75487cce30250fec94147abab0397f2b8 sha256:737f40e80b7ff641f24b759d64f7ec489be0ef4e0c16a9780b795dbe972b38d2 sha256:5f70bf18a086007016e948b04aed3b82103a36bea41755b6cddfaf10ace3c6ef] }}
```

When you define a format without the brackets, that's no longer a variable to print but the literal character `.` to output, which is all you saw. Note, a user readable output can be received by not formatting the output at all, e.g.:

```
$ docker inspect ubuntu:latest
```

And if you want a specific field from that output, then formatting to extract that specific field is useful, e.g.:

```
$ docker inspect -f '{{ .Created }}'  ubuntu:latest
2016-05-27T14:15:02.359284074Z
```

Comment: Heh, I totally forgot about the `-f` flag when I started using `jq`. Time to rein that back in!

Comment: Thank you BMitch. I understand it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are thinking the dot should do, but you are using the 'format' option with the format `.` provided. It is seen as a literal string.

if you provide any other format, e.g. `format xx`, you'd get that string.

compare:

> docker inspect redis:2.6 -f xx
>   xx

Comment: I saw "docker inspect -f . ubuntu:latest" in one of the Jenkins job and saw dot as the output  and did not know what it was doing.